# is it a good practice to keep on upgrading or downgrading keras and tensorflow versions while working with different projects?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

is it a good practice to keep on upgrading or downgrading keras and tensorflow versions  while working with different projects ?
Is there any other way out?

Comment: Have you heard of virtual environments?